# MySQL -- Dynamic Insert into table with same name

Tags: mysql

I need help with query that will take all tables with prefix "tifa_" in "centraldb" database and copy all data in same name table that ends with "_hist". Column name should be matched. as_of_date need to be yesterday day when running the query.

I have around 70 tables and this is example of 4 tables:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMGCi.jpg)

Thank you!

Comment: Show your attempts to solve your problem/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.